# Access to filenames and preprocess data inside queue in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a directory of image files and corresponding information files (containing some further info for each image). It looks like this:

> data/images/001.png
>
> data/info/001.txt
>
> data/info2/001.txt

I can load the images using...

```python
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)
reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
_, value = reader.read(filename_queue)`
```

... but I also need the information from the associated files (actually I have some functions which use the image filename as input, preprocess the path for info, preprocess the data, and return a numpy array). But now, I am confused how to pass it with the queue. It seems I need access to the filenames inside the queue to call my functions at each step.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`tf.py_func()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func) to contain your python/numpy pre-processing from the filenames, also knowing that [`reader.read()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/WholeFileReader#read) returns both the `key` (filename) and `value` (file content), e.g.

```
def my_preprocessing_from_filename(filename):
    # This is your pre-processing, e.g.:
    image_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(str(filename)))[0]
    image_info_path = os.path.join("data/info", "{}.txt".format(image_name))
    image_info = numpy.loadtxt(image_info_path, dtype=numpy.int64)
    # ... or whatever you do to load/process the info
    return image_info

filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)
reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
my_image_info  = tf.py_func(my_preprocessing_from_filename, [key], tf.int64)
# ...
```

---

*note:* Depending what your pre-processing is, you could consider porting it into Tensorflow operations, using the TF [`string_ops`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/string_ops) methods to get your info filenames from the image ones, e.g.:

```
def my_tf_preprocessing_from_filename(filename):
    # Get basename:
    image_name = tf.string_split(filename, delimiter='/').values[-1]
    # Remove ext (supposing no other "." in name):  
    image_name = tf.string_split(filename, delimiter='.').values[0]    
    image_info = tf.reduce_join(["data/info", image_name, ".txt"])
    _, info_value = reader.read(filename_queue)
    # ... further pre-process your info
    return info_value

filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)
reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
my_image_info = my_tf_preprocessing_from_filename([key])
```

Comment: Actually my filenames consist of pairs: `[[image1, image2], [image2, image3],...]` and I need to pass into function `filename1` and `filename2`. So, I should create 2 filename_queue and can pass it like this? `tf.py_func(my_preprocessing_from_filename, [key1, key2], tf.int64)`

Comment: It's quite hard to answer without knowing more about your pipeline and goals. Dealing with image pairs is a different problem so I would suggest to investigate (e.g. [this other SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38827264/how-to-use-tensorflow-reader-and-queue-to-read-two-file-at-same-time), [`tf.data.Dataset.zip()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#zip), etc.) and create a new question if needed.